# Posting from form on Razor Page returns blank page

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, razor

If I create a form using form tag helper the submit button triggers the OnPost event

```
<form method="post" asp-page="login">
```

However if I use

```
<form method="post" action="/auth/login">
```

The OnPost event is not fired.
And yes, asp-page="login" translates tp "/auth/login".
Even if I use asp-page="login" and copy the url from the console inspector and paste onto my cshtml page, a blank page is returned.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` into the second form.When you use the second form,it will lose a hidden input which contains the antiforgery token.

```
<form method="post" action="/auth/login">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Is there a way to display an error when there is no antiforgerytoken rather than just a blank page?